# error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, firefox, mozilla, gtk-2

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to download a a 3.6.x firefox version. I've gotten [this one](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/3.6.2/linux-i686/en-US/).
According to the README, all I have to do is unpack, enter the folder and run `./firefox`. However, I get the following error when I do that:

```
./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

But when I run `locate libgtk-x11`, it is installed:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23
```

Does anyone know where `./firefox` looks for? My guess is that I have to create a link between folders, I just do not know which.

---

Edit 1: After installing `libgtk2.0-0:i386` and trying to run `./firefox` again, the libraries libgobject-2.0 can not be found. I try to install them with `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0:i368`, but I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-refdbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dev:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-dbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-bin:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil-dev:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-tests:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data' instead of 'libglib2.0-data:i386'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc' instead of 'libglib2.0-doc:i386'
libglib2.0-data is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-doc is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0:i386 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-cil:i386 : Depends: cli-common:i386 (>= 0.5.6) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libmono-corlib4.0-cil:i386 (>= 2.10.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil:i386 (>= 2.10.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Maybe `libglib2` is not the library that contains `libgobject`?

Answer (score 55):

Your system is 64-bit, but since you want to run a 32-bit version of Firefox, you need to install the 32-bit version of the library:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: thanks! I now get `libgobject-2.0` not found, I have tried with `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0:i368`, but dependencies such as `cli-common:i368`, and others are not installable. Any ideas? Should I install a 32-bit system in a virtual box?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would want to pull `cli-common`, please edit your question to add the **full** output of `apt install libglib2.0-0:i386`.

Comment: It interprets `libglib2.0-0:i368` as a regex and tries to install many packets. I am looking for the correct library for `libgobject-2.0`.  Or you think it is something else? (Edit has been done)

Comment: It is really `libglib2.0-0`, not `libglib2.0`.

Comment: after `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386`, the libraries `libjobject-2.0.so.o` still can not be found. Thanks for the correction, though.

Comment: You really need to be more careful, now you write `libjobject`...

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. It is `libgobject-2.0.so.0`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. @fkraiem answer made me figure out another possibility that fix my issue.

I was trying to run a app in the wrong architecture. So make sure if you are trying to install the right app for your system a 32 or 64 bits.