# Cannot open MongoDB Compass in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: mongodb

installed successfully MongoDB Compass on Ubuntu 18.10. But when I try to run it, it refuses to start without showing anything.  I am a newbie in MongoDB. What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download newest beta version of Compass
`mongodb-compass-community-beta_1.18.0_beta.1_amd64.deb`
It works.
I have "debian testing" as OS, and newest version of `mongodb` (compiled from github source).
I had the same problem like you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by reverting to an earlier version of MongoDB compass.

Workaround:

1. Use an earlier version -- I followed the instructions @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122804/mongodb-compass-cannot-be-opened-in-ubuntu-18-10 in the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/10611387/nimesh-kumar.  This then lead to another error when executing:

   `$ mongodb-compass`

   `mongodb-compass: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
2. Satisfy requirement of earlier version -- To solve this I followed the answer by https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem at [error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836142/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-no-such-file-or-direc)

Hopefully this helps you.