# MongoDB Compass Error in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mongodb

Running compass stop and know it's giving below error

`mongodb-compass: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I uninstall and then install the error is same. even I tried the old version too. I searched and found this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089381/cannot-open-mongodb-compass-in-ubuntu-18-10) but it does not work for me.

[SS of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vW9B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a description how you can get the dependencies installed.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me) MongoDB should have included that in the manual for installing compass.

Basically you just need to type

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then your install compass with dpkg

Comment: Nope, buddy I already try this command it didn't work for me.