# How to install unity3D 2019 in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: unity

Is there a way to install [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/unity) 2019 in Ubuntu 19.10? With or without using WINE? I know I can install 2018 but I wanted the latest version ([system requirements](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.2.12)).

Comment: Wine isn't a very good solution to run Windows .exe files. You might try Virtualbox with a Windows guest OS, and then install the Unity3D editor there. There may not be enough resources there to run it efficiently (without a little tweaking).

Comment: for example I saw a blog saying that U can install Unity 2018 in a ubuntu ou something similar and it works on my ubuntu but probably there's a way to install the 2019 version no?

Comment: Are you using Wine and Unity3D 2018 now? Can't you install 2019 the same way?

Comment: with the 2018 version I don't need wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity doesn't support 19.10 only 18.04 at the moment.
But to get it working 19.10 you need to [download UnityHub](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v2-0-0-release.677485/), but there is also flatpak as well (which seems to be fine).

1. Install `libgtk` package using

   ```
   sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
   ```

   If you don't have it, it won't open for some reason. But if you open from terminal, it will give you some errors which lead me to this link : [error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836142/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-no-such-file-or-direc)
2. You'll probably get some blank error messages in the console.

   Add this line

   ```
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
   ```

   at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file ([source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unidentifiable-errors-in-unity-console-on-ubuntu-19-04-fixed.690757)).
   Then

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install libssl1.0
   ```

   I think you need install it, I can't actually remember, maybe just update/upgrade is enough
3. You will probably get some burst compiler errors, so just install

   ```
   sudo apt install libncurses5
   ```

   and you are off to the races, as said [from this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-1-0f2-dllnotfoundexception-unable-to-load-the-unmanaged-library-burst.664705/)

There are also other issues with Unity in Linux but so far, these are main ones to get you up and running.

Also visit the [Linux Editor forum](https://forum.unity.com/forums/linux-editor.93/), there are lot of people there reporting/solving issues. But also most importantly, report issues official to Unity. Its the only way to Linux editor will get better.

Comment: I just installed Unity on Ubuntu 19.10 a day ago and didn't need to do any of this. Unity is improving their Linux support ten fold. Woo!

Answer (score 1):

The Unity3D folks don't make it easy to find Linux install files.

See https://unity.com/

See https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/05/30/announcing-the-unity-editor-for-linux/?_ga=2.186801064.1413184186.1573999883-1037702168.1573859546

See https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v-1-6-0-is-now-available.640792/?_ga=2.142292786.1413184186.1573999883-1037702168.1573859546

Download unityhub at https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHub.AppImage?_ga=2.79420692.1413184186.1573999883-1037702168.1573859546